# Execution default of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test failed

Tags: maven, jar, automated-tests, soapui

Our SOAPUI test project has recently started failing with the message:

```
59626 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
59626 [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
59626 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
59627 [INFO] Total time: 56.863 s
59627 [INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-06T09:57:17+00:00
59703 [INFO] Final Memory: 13M/56M
59704 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
59745 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test (default) on project SIFIntegrationTest: Execution default of goal com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1:test failed: Plugin com.smartbear.soapui:soapui-maven-plugin:4.6.1 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:2.0.1, groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.8.0: Could not find artifact fife:rsyntaxtextarea:jar:2.0.1 in smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository (http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/) -> [Help 1]
```

We havent made any changes to it for weeks but now Maven cannot find a couple of JARs.

The pom.xml is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.sif</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-repository</id>
            <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>smartbear-sweden-plugin-repository</id>
            <url>http://smartbearsoftware.com/repository/maven2/</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.7.1</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.smartbear.soapui</groupId>
                <artifactId>soapui-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <projectFile>Tests-soapui-project.xml</projectFile>
                    <outputFolder>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</outputFolder>
                    <junitReport>true</junitReport>
                    <printReport>false</printReport>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    <phase>test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I guess SmartBear has changed their Maven repos, is there a way to fix this?

Our project is on a GitLab CI / CD pipeline using a Maven Image, we have tried directly on GitLab.com to eliminate our network and it still fails there.

Cheers,
Steve

Comment: 4.6.1 is quite outdated! My guess is dependencies that old have been purged from the repos. Try updating to a more recent version of SoapUI. You might need to update your project as well.

Comment: Yes I agree it is old, but it was working 4 weeks ago and SmartBear's example still refers to it in the basic configuration section: https://www.soapui.org/test-automation/maven/maven-2-x.html

Comment: Same problem, found 5.5.0 worked ok (note 5.6.0 is Java 9+).  Can browse versions here: https://rapi.tools.ops.smartbear.io/nexus/content/groups/public/com/smartbear/soapui/soapui-maven-plugin/